# cuda kernel not executed for all blockIdx

Tags: c++, cuda

I isolated a bug in my code and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. When I execute the following code, the CUDA kernel is not executed for all blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__
void dummy_test_kernel()
{
  printf("grid = (%i, %i, %i), block = (%i, %i, %i),
    bid (%i,%i,%i), tid (%i, %i, %i)\n",
    gridDim.x, gridDim.y, gridDim.z,
    blockDim.x, blockDim.y, blockDim.z,
    blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y, blockIdx.z,
    threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  dummy_test_kernel<<<62,256>>>();
  if(cudaDeviceSynchronize())
    printf("something went wrong in the kernel execution\n");
  return 0;
}
```

For example, I never see a block with blockIdx.x < 20 printing anything. In case that might help to figure out my mistake, here are the information returned by the deviceQuery found in the CUDA samples:

```
Device 0: "GeForce GTX 675M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147155968 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors, ( 48) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1240 MHz (1.24 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1500 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: You are probably just overflow the kernel printf buffer. The runtime assigns a fixed amount of space for the buffer. Your kernel is probably producing too much output

Comment: Yes, that was an overflow. By adding a test `if( blockIdx.x < 20 )` before the `printf`, I see blocks with smaller x ids.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to print the error given by *cudaDeviceSynchronize*
2. Try to execute your code with *cuda-memcheck ./program*
3. If point 2) returns an error use *cuda-gdb* to debug it.
4. You are launching a 1D kernel of 62 thread-blocks of 256 threads each. I expect your outputs to be grid (62,1,1) block(256,1,1) bid(b_x, 1, 1) tid (t_x,1,1)